# Group by or distinct - how can I do for 3 tables

Tags: sql, image, group-by, sql-order-by

```
SELECT c.urun_id, a.kat_adi, b.resim_yolu, b.sira, 
c.urun_sira, c.urun_adi
FROM kategoriler a,resimler b, urunler c 
where  a.kat_id=c.kat_id and c.urun_id=b.urun_id
order by c.urun_sira,b.sira
```

There are two record with `urun_id = 17`. I want to return only one record. I have `category`, `products`, `images` tables. User has added 2 photos in `images` table where `urun_id=17`.

But I want to show only one record which has minimum value in `sira`.

If the output of the query is

- 25 ~ pc ~ 3
- 17 ~ phone ~ 2
- 17 ~ phone ~ 4

Then, I want to return

- **17 ~ phone ~ 2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLServer2005+ use [**ROW_NUMBER**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function

```
 ;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT c.urun_id, a.kat_adi, b.resim_yolu, b.sira, 
         c.urun_sira, c.urun_adi, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.urun_id ORDER BY b.sira) AS rn
  FROM kategoriler a JOIN urunler c ON a.kat_id=c.kat_id
                     JOIN resimler b ON c.urun_id=b.urun_id
  )
  SELECT *
  FROM cte
  WHERE rn = 1
  ORDER BY urun_sira, sira
```

Other way

```
  SELECT c.urun_id, a.kat_adi, b.resim_yolu, b.sira, 
         c.urun_sira, c.urun_adi         
  FROM kategoriler a JOIN urunler c ON a.kat_id=c.kat_id
                     JOIN resimler b ON c.urun_id=b.urun_id  
  WHERE EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM resimler r
                WHERE b.urun_id = r.urun_id
                HAVING MIN(r.sira) = b.sira
                )
  ORDER BY c.urun_sira, b.sira
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, this should work,

```
SELECT c.urun_id, a.kat_adi, b.resim_yolu, min(b.sira),
       c.urun_sira, c.urun_adi
FROM kategoriler a,resimler b, urunler c
where a.kat_id=c.kat_id
and c.urun_id=b.urun_id
group by c.urun_id, a.kat_adi, b.resim_yolu,
       c.urun_sira, c.urun_adi
order by c.urun_sira,b.sira
```

Comment: @david5 This is a generic query which will give you the row for each `urun_id` corresponding to the minimum `sira` value. If you want specifically for urun_id = 17, then add `AND URUN_ID = 17` in the `WHERE` condition.

Comment: Msg 8127, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Column "resimler.sira" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @david5 Either remove that from the order by condition and use `order by c.urun_sira` or use `order by c.urun_sira, min(b.sira)`

Comment: SELECT  Distinct(c.urun_id), a.kat_adi, b.resim_yolu, min(b.sira),
       c.urun_sira, c.urun_adi
FROM kategoriler a,resimler b, urunler c 
where a.kat_id=c.kat_id
and c.urun_id=b.urun_id
group by c.urun_id, a.kat_adi, b.resim_yolu,
       c.urun_sira, c.urun_adi
order by c.urun_sira, min(b.sira)    not working please help

Comment: @david5 Can you build those three tables and sample data in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) so that I can help you out?

Comment: @david5 Here you go. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c2dbf/7/0    SELECT c.urun_id, a.kat_adi, b.resim_yolu, min(b.sira) AS siraa,
       c.urun_sira, c.urun_adi
FROM kategoriler a,resimler b, urunler c
where a.kat_id=c.kat_id
and c.urun_id=b.urun_id
group by c.urun_id, a.kat_adi, b.resim_yolu,
       c.urun_sira, c.urun_adi
order by c.urun_sira, siraa